# Django Setup Error: View is not callable

Tags: python, django

I got a basic Django setup working on my webhost, then I copied it down to my local machine.  Both my local and my remote are using the same version of Django, and the same database (Postgres) with the same exact `settings.py`.

The thing is, when I run `manage.py runserver` on my local, and then browse to localhost, I get:

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /
Could not import myapp.main. View is not callable.
```

The view does exist though, and works perfectly fine on my remote.  When I look at the PYTHONPATH in the debug output it includes the base directory of my django setup, and the "main" app is in the INSTALLED_APPS in my `settings.py`.

Basically everything is setup the same as on my remote (except that the remote is using Apache and I'm using runserver), at least as far as I can tell, but they are behaving differently.  Does anyone have any clue what could be wrong?

**EDIT:**

It turns out I'm an idiot, and one of my files (`urls.py`) on the server never made it in to the commit.  As a result, my local file wasn't what I thought it was, and I failed to realize the problem.  Once I updated `urls.py` everything worked.

Comment: Check items in your `sys.path` one by one. The error says that it found `myapp.main` but it is not a function (callable). See [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/urlresolvers.py#L108).

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: 1.6.2 on both my local and remote.

Comment: @alexce I know, but the thing is that exact same `myapp.main` is callable on the server.  What should I check `sys.path` for?

Comment: Are you using pip on your production?

Answer (score 1):

put 'myapp' in your settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (

'myapp',
```

)

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.main', name='main'),
```

check that in views.py, a function named 'main' should be there

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I only have "myapp.main" in urls.py and settings.py.  When I change `url(r'^$', 'myapp.main', name='main'),` to `url(r'^$', 'main', name='main'),` I then get a "TypeError at / 'str' object is not callable/", and when I change the INSTALLED_APPS in settings to just "main" `manage.py runserver` fails with an "ImportError: No module named main".

Comment: according to you, 'main' should be a function, you should know where it is, such as 'myapp.views.main',check that, I have corrected my answer